# Creating and Assigning Public IP to the EC2 instance created with ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, ansible

while creating a AWS instance from the playbook i was trying to attach an elastic ip with the server.  and am getting this error.

---

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'instance_ids'"
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/ubuntu/aws.retry

---

---

- name: aws instance creating
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: True
  vars:
        os_image: ami-063aa838bd7631e0b
        location: us-west-1
        pem: recippeeps-c
        vpc_subnet: subnet-fc5664a7
        server_name: sagar-test
        instance_type: t2.micro
        firewall_name: sagar
        description: sagar_test_rule
        count: 1

  tasks:

  ```
    - name: ec2 security group
      ec2_group:
              name: "{{firewall_name}}"
              region: "{{location}}"
              description: "{{description}}"
              state: present
              rules:
                      - proto: tcp
                        from_port: 80
                        to_port: 80
                        cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0

                      - proto: tcp
                        from_port: 22
                        to_port: 22
                        cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0

                      - proto: tcp
                        from_port: 443
                        to_port: 443
                        cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0

      register: firewall

    - name: Debug firewall facts
      debug: msg="{{firewall}}"


    - name: creating AWS instance
      ec2:
              key_name: "{{pem}}"
              instance_type: "{{instance_type}}"
              region: "{{location}}"
              image: "{{os_image}}"
              termination_protection: no
              group_id: "{{firewall.group_id}}"
              wait: true
              count: "{{count}}"
              instance_tags:
                      Name: "{{server_name}}"
                      state: present
              vpc_subnet_id: "{{vpc_subnet}}"
              assign_public_ip: yes

      register: ec2

    - name: Debug EC2 facts
      debug: msg="{{ec2}}"


    - name: Providing a Static IP
      ec2_eip:
              in_vpc: yes
              reuse_existing_ip_allowed: yes
              region: "{{location}}"
              device_id: "{{ec2.instance_ids}}"
              wait_timeout: "20"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear

> "'dict object' has no attribute 'instance_ids'"

when you try to use it

```
    device_id: "{{ ec2.instance_ids }}"
```

You registered and printed *ec2*

```
  register: ec2
- name: Debug EC2 facts
  debug: msg="{{ ec2 }}"
```

Take a look where *instance_ids* is, or post *ec2*.